# Get the Total ItemHeight of all the Items arbitrarily defined heights in the TListView at Runtime (Delphi Rio 10.3 FMX)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

How to get the total ItemHeight (variably defined) of the items in the TListView at runtime.

The item height, by the way, is arbitrarily defined at runtime using the event UpdateObjects and I should be able to get it from there but I am not getting the correct height for some reasons. I feel it should be easier if I get those after it is defined.

I've tried this approach but no success. But my code `ListView1.Items[i].Height` looks not right here.

```
TotalItemHeight := 0;
for i = 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
begin
   TotalItemHeight := TotalItemHeight + ListView1.Items[i].Height;  //I need help here..   
end;
```

[image: screenshot]

.FMX Procedure:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListView.Types,
  FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, FMX.ListView,
  Markov;

type
  TVariableHeight = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListView1: TListView;
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
      const AItem: TListViewItem);
  private
    FChain: TChain;
    FBitmaps: TDictionary<Integer, TBitmap>;
    FText: TArray<string>;
    procedure ReadText;
    function GetDimensionBitmap(const Width, Height: Single): TBitmap;
  public
    function GetTextHeight(const D: TListItemText; const Width: Single; const Text: string): Integer;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  VariableHeight: TVariableHeight;

implementation

uses
  System.IOUtils, FMX.TextLayout;

{$R *.fmx}

// Create a new item with random text of random length
procedure TVariableHeight.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReadText;
  ListView1.Items.Add.Data['txtMain'] := FText[Random(Length(FText))];
  // with classic appearances, use Text property
  //ListView1.Items.Add.Text := FChain.Generate(Random(100) + 5);
end;

function TVariableHeight.GetDimensionBitmap(const Width, Height: Single): TBitmap;
  procedure Arrow(C: TCanvas; P: array of TPointF);
  begin
    C.DrawLine(P[0], P[1], 1.0);
    C.DrawLine(P[0], P[2], 1.0);
    C.DrawLine(P[0], P[3], 1.0);
  end;

var
  EndP1, EndP2: TPointF;
  TextBitmap: TBitmap;
  IntHeight: Integer;
begin
  IntHeight := Trunc(Height);

  if FBitmaps = nil then
    FBitmaps := TDictionary<Integer, TBitmap>.Create;
  if not FBitmaps.TryGetValue(IntHeight, Result) then
  begin
    Result := TBitmap.Create(Trunc(Width), IntHeight);
    FBitmaps.Add(IntHeight, Result);
    if Result.Canvas.BeginScene then
    begin
      Result.Canvas.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.Null);
      Result.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Darkgray;

      // Draw the arrows
      EndP1 := TPointF.Create(Width/2, 0);
      EndP2 := TPointF.Create(Width/2, Height);
      Arrow(Result.Canvas,
        [EndP1, TPointF.Create(Width/2, Height/2 - Width/2),
         EndP1 + TPointF.Create(-2, 5), EndP1 + TPointF.Create(2, 5)]);
      Arrow(Result.Canvas,
        [EndP2, TPointF.Create(Width/2, Height/2 + Width/2),
         EndP2 + TPointF.Create(-2, -5), EndP2 + TPointF.Create(2, -5)]);

      // Draw the dimension text
      TextBitmap := TBitmap.Create(Trunc(Width), Trunc(Width));
      try
        if TextBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
          with TextBitmap.Canvas do
          begin
            Clear(TAlphaColorRec.Null);
            Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Darkgray;
            FillText(TextBitmap.BoundsF, ''.Format('%d', [IntHeight]), False, 1,
              [], TTextAlign.Center, TTextAlign.Center);
            EndScene;
          end;
        TextBitmap.Rotate(90);
        Result.Canvas.DrawBitmap(TextBitmap, TextBitmap.BoundsF,
          TextBitmap.BoundsF.CenterAt(Result.BoundsF), 1);
      finally
        TextBitmap.Free;
      end;

      Result.Canvas.EndScene;
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TVariableHeight.Destroy;
var
  Key: Integer;
begin
  FChain.Free;
  if FBitmaps <> nil then
    for Key in FBitmaps.Keys do
      FBitmaps[Key].Free;
  FBitmaps.Free;
  inherited;
end;

// Calculate height for text drawable D
function TVariableHeight.GetTextHeight(const D: TListItemText; const Width: single; const Text: string): Integer;
var
  Layout: TTextLayout;
begin
  // Create a TTextLayout to measure text dimensions
  Layout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  try
    Layout.BeginUpdate;
    try
      // Initialize layout parameters with those of the drawable
      Layout.Font.Assign(D.Font);
      Layout.VerticalAlign := D.TextVertAlign;
      Layout.HorizontalAlign := D.TextAlign;
      Layout.WordWrap := D.WordWrap;
      Layout.Trimming := D.Trimming;
      Layout.MaxSize := TPointF.Create(Width, TTextLayout.MaxLayoutSize.Y);
      Layout.Text := Text;
    finally
      Layout.EndUpdate;
    end;
    // Get layout height
    Result := Round(Layout.Height);
    // Add one em to the height
    Layout.Text := 'm';
    Result := Result + Round(Layout.Height);
  finally
    Layout.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TVariableHeight.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  Drawable: TListItemText;
  SizeImg: TListItemImage;
  Text: string;
  AvailableWidth: Single;
begin
  SizeImg := TListItemImage(AItem.View.FindDrawable('imgSize'));
  AvailableWidth := TListView(Sender).Width - TListView(Sender).ItemSpaces.Left
    - TListView(Sender).ItemSpaces.Right - SizeImg.Width;
  ShowMessage(TListView(Sender).Height.ToString);

  // Find the text drawable which is used to calcualte item size.
  // For dynamic appearance, use item name.
  // For classic appearances use TListViewItem.TObjectNames.Text
  // Drawable := TListItemText(AItem.View.FindDrawable(TListViewItem.TObjectNames.Text));
  Drawable := TListItemText(AItem.View.FindDrawable('txtMain'));
  Text := Drawable.Text;

  // Randomize the font when updating for the first time
  if Drawable.TagFloat = 0 then
  begin
    Drawable.Font.Size := 1; // Ensure that default font sizes do not play against us
    Drawable.Font.Size := 10 + Random(4) * 4;

    Drawable.TagFloat := Drawable.Font.Size;
    if Text.Length < 100 then
      Drawable.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
  end;

  // Calculate item height based on text in the drawable
  AItem.Height := GetTextHeight(Drawable, AvailableWidth, Text);
  Drawable.Height := AItem.Height;
  Drawable.Width := AvailableWidth;

  SizeImg.OwnsBitmap := False;
  SizeImg.Bitmap := GetDimensionBitmap(SizeImg.Width, AItem.Height);
end;

procedure TVariableHeight.ReadText;
const
  Delimiters: array of char = [#10, #13];
var
  Reader: TStreamReader;
  Stream: TResourceStream;
begin
  if Length(FText) = 0 then
  begin
    Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'Blabla', RT_RCDATA);
    Reader := TStreamReader.Create(Stream);
    try
      FText := Reader.ReadToEnd.Split(Delimiters, TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty)
    finally
      Reader.Close;
      Reader.Free;
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

.FMX File

```
object VariableHeight: TVariableHeight
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'VariableHeight'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 510
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListView1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    OnUpdateObjects = ListView1UpdateObjects
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 510.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 436.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'txtMain'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.TextAlign = Leading
        Appearance.WordWrap = True
        Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
        Appearance.VertAlign = Center
      end
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'imgSize'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TImageObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.ScalingMode = Original
        Appearance.Width = 30.000000000000000000
        Appearance.Align = Trailing
      end>
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
      end>
  end
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Padding.Top = 4.000000000000000000
    Padding.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 510.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    object Label1: TLabel
      Align = Contents
      Size.Width = 510.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'toollabel'
      TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
      Text = 'Variable Row Height Demo'
    end
    object Button1: TButton
      Align = Right
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 448.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 4.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 57.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 36.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'listitembutton'
      TabOrder = 1
      Text = 'Fill List'
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There's just a typo in your loop.

Comment: @Olivier Can you be  specific. I checked it which one is typo error?

Comment: Instead of 1, use i in the Items array.